# Laravel deferred image binding

Tags: laravel, image, binding

What is the best way to bind image to model that is not exists yet.

For example if I am currently filling form with some data for Post model, and have image upload functionality like CKEditor or Dropzone.js, that process and sends images to server via AJAX, while main form is not submitted.

What I came up with is to create class named `DeferredModel` that have attributes of `user_id` or `session_id`, and `form_url`, and bind images to this model. After submitting the form and creating the main model I can detach images from `DeferredModel` to Post model.

Comment: Why do you need to bind them to an existing model at upload time? After upload you can send a response back to your clientside of what path it should put in the final model and then submit that as e.g. a hidden form field.

Comment: @apokryfos, I want to save it for scenarios when user has left the form without submitting, so I can delete this images later. Or user can refresh the page with form, and hidden fields with uploaded images data, and lose attachments.